# Display PowerPoint notes on iPhone during presentation?

Tags: iphone, windows, ms-office, ios, slideshow

When presenting a PowerPoint (.pptx) document, I'll likely have a clicker but cannot count on having visible access to the notes I've written inside it for each slide to help me present.

The presentation will be running on a Windows machine.

Is there an app for the iPhone where I can not only open the PowerPoint document, but easily read the notes only, slide-by-slide?

Alternatively, what solutions do you suggest? Google Docs?

Comment: The best imho is: Keynote + Keynote Remote. But it requires a Mac.

Comment: Right, but the "presentation will be running on a Windows machine" — nothing can do about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at Slideshow Remote?
http://www.slideshowremote.com/

This is a well-regarded app (with both free and pro versions) that can remotely control PowerPoint on a PC and allow you to view and edit the presenter's notes.